# What JAXB bean corresponds to this JSON?

Tags: java, jquery, json, jakarta-ee, jersey

The JSON is:

```
{"list": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
```

Here's how I implement the JAXB bean:

```
package com.anon.sortweb.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class JsonBean {
    @XmlElement(name="list")
    private int[] list;

    public JsonBean() {}

    public void setList(int[] list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public int[] getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

My web application works fine (I'm able to successfully access other resources) but this one resource (that I pass my JSON to) returns a 415 Media Type Unsupported exception.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("text/html")
public String sortAndReturnHtml(JsonBean listBean) { ... }
```

How do I correctly write my JAXB bean to encapsulate a list of integers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you're probably using Jersey.  Have you looked here: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html?  Also: is the request content-type "application/json"?

Comment: Hi Paul. I am using content-type "application/json". I'll look into that documentation, but any answers in the meantime would be much appreciated!

Comment: The javascript code is only a demo?

Comment: Yes, it's only a demo. I'm going to parse the textarea's input much more carefully after I get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Your JAXB bean is a perfectly reasonable representation of your JSON data.  The [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) spec does not cover JSON binding so the answer ultimately comes down to how/if your JAX-RS implementation interprets JAXB metadata to produce/consume JSON.

**Demo**

Below is how it would work with MOXy.

```
package forum13648734;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {JsonBean.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum13648734/input.json");
        JsonBean jsonBean = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, JsonBean.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(jsonBean, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
{"list":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: Thanks! I was using Jersey as my JAX-RS implementation, and I didn't specify any way to consume JSONs. I ended up adding the Jackson dependency and voila, it worked. It was nice to hear from you and learn about MOXy. Happy holidays - ktm.